# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'build_exe' | How could i fix it?

Tags: python, py2exe

I've made a simple program, using py2exe, I wanna convert it to exe file, but I'm stuck with an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'build_exe' when I run the program! Can anyone help me t fix it?
```

My code:

```
# Displays warning messages in loop

from tkinter import * from tkinter import messagebox from distutils.core import setup import py2exe

setup(console=["System32.py"], options={'py2exe': {'packages': ['tkinter', 'messagebox', 'distutils']}})
# to exe

root = Tk() root.title("System32") root.config(bg="Red") root.wm_resizable(0, 0) root.geometry("4000x4000")

Label(root, text="Please wait... while formating your PC!", font="FixedSys 25", fg="Red", bg="Black").place(x=300, y=200) Label(root, text="Coded by: #AVD001", font="FixedSys 20", fg="Black", bg="Red").place(x=550, y=450)

while True:
    messagebox.showwarning(title="#AVD001", message="Formating your pc...")
```

I expected the program to be run successfully but it shows the error!

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'build_exe'
```

Please help me! Useful answers are appreciated!

Comment: `py2exe` only supports Python 3.3 and earlier. If you are using a modern version of Python look at `pyinstaller` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BoarGules, you got my soul back to me, Cheers!